# Can I program C++/CLI using Visual Studio Express 2008?

Tags: c++-cli, visual-c++-2008-express

Are any of the Visual Studio Express editions able to work with C++/CLI code?  Currently when I go to "Add File" in either the C# 2008 or C++ 2008 versions I do not see the option for creating C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new project in Visual C++ Express, any of the "CLR" project types is a C++/CLI application (e.g. uses the `/clr` compilation switch to include the .NET runtime). Pick either a Console or Windows Forms project type to get up and running quickly.

You can also enable CLR support for an existing C++ project by flipping the option under Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Common Language Runtime support.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Visual C++ express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP) version. Visual Studio Express doesn't really exist, because for every language, there is a different program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Express Edition installed, so I can't verify this, but I seem to recall that C++/CLI was just about the only thing you can do with a fresh install of Visual C++ Express.  The native framework MFC isn't included, to do native Windows programming you need to download and install the Win32 Platform SDK (now renamed just Windows SDK).  But .NET capabilities are provided in the default install.

Now, the wizard doesn't use the terminology "C++/CLI", which may be the source of your confusion.  Every project type in the .NET category will be coded in C++/CLI though.